strictNullChecks and array access
Consider this TypeScript code:
export class Lala {
  id: number = Infinity;
  arr: { [key: number]: string } = {};

  get(nr: number): string {
    return this.arr[nr];
  }
}

const lala = new Lala();

const x: string = lala.get(555);

For my understanding the function signature get(nr: number): string and the assignment of x should throw a TypeScript error, because the value can be undefined if an index was given which did not exist in the array. It doesn't, even if strictNullChecks is enabled (which seemed to address the exact issue) and I get exactly the type of runtime errors TypeScript is created to avoid.
Why is the given code not raising an error and is there some switch for doing so?

I don't see why you think that's a strict null check problem - what you have there is unchecked indexed access: https://tsplay.dev/N5YzBN

@jonrsharpe Thanks that everything i wanted to know. I did't find the noUncheckedIndexedAccess option, i have no idea why because it's right there.
